# How to get google-services.json from Developer console?

Tags: android, google-api, developer-console, google-play-services

How to get `google-services.json` from Developer console after the project has been created and services were enabled? I want to generate it from Developer console and not from Developer docs.

Comment: on developer console in clicked api screen there will be an option to `Get Configuration File`. Click on it and follow all steps

Comment: @VivekMishra In Enabled APIs Screen there's no option to download this file.

Comment: which api you are using?

Comment: Analytics for Android

Comment: check mine link too . It's directly for Analytics Api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the steps here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

After all parameters are added you will get a download link for your `google-services.json`

Comment: Thanks.. Though i was looking for some option in Developer console directly but this is really useful.

Comment: Url is not active already

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to get Configuration file

[Analytics Api Configuration File](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#get-config)