# How to configure the Google Services SDK for Unity 5.6?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

This is the SDK of google for Unity.
Link: https://github.com/unity-plugins/google-services-unity
I couldn't understand the Quick Setup. How will I replace the google-services.json (see the quick setup guide in the link above) ?
I am using this plugin because I differently imported AdMob SDK & Google Play SDK for Unity and they are giving me nightmares. So trying this SDK.

Comment: I suppose you have to download it. [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en) UPD: also, see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591663/how-to-get-google-services-json-from-developer-console)